# Set attributes to a class from constructor parameters in a clean way

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this code for a class that receives some parameters, and I'm assigning them as object properties once each time.

```
class InitAnimation {
  constructor(settingsAnimation, settingButton, isHelp, isEnd) {
    // Initialized the configuration for  main animation.
    this.settingsAnimation = settingsAnimation;
    this.settingButton = settingButton;
    this.yes = null;
    this.no = null;
    this.isHelp = isHelp;
    this.isEnd = isEnd;
    this.initConfig();
  }
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this in ES6, in which I just can take the arguments key-values and assign them to the object as computed property names? Something like:

```
class InitAnimation {
  constructor(settingsAnimation, settingButton, isHelp, isEnd) {
    // Initialized the configuration for  main animation.
    // I know this doesn't work on 'arguments'
    arguments.forEach(key => this[key] = arguments[key]);
    this.initConfig();
}
```

For this case I can't modify the way parameters are sent because that would imply changing everyone else's code and the project is kinda big right now. Can I do this in a better way without changing how parameters are passed?

Comment: [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in ES2015+ you can use `Object.assign` and shorthand properties:

```
constructor(settingsAnimation, settingButton, isHelp, isEnd) {
  // Initialized the configuration for  main animation.
  Object.assign(this, {settingsAnimation, settingButton, isHelp, isEnd});
  this.yes = null;
  this.no = null;
  this.initConfig();
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class InitAnimation {
    constructor(settingsAnimation, settingButton, isHelp, isEnd) {
      // Initialized the configuration for  main animation.
      Object.assign(this, {settingsAnimation, settingButton, isHelp, isEnd});
      this.yes = null;
      this.no = null;
      this.initConfig();
    }
    initConfig() {
    }
}
const a = new InitAnimation("a", "b", "c", "d");
console.log(a);
```

Comment: I think the asker doesn't want to have to re-list all the arguments.

Comment: @DuncanThacker: The only *reasonable* way to avoid it is to accept an object, and even then, you'd be merging *all* of that object's properties (which may not be safe). The above is concise and avoids unnecessary duplication (e.g., each param name is listed only twice rather than three times).

Comment: @DuncanThacker: As estus said, minification. There's also markedly high overhead relative to value, the fact that `toString` wasn't even standardized until recently, different browsers behave differently with regard to comments, ...

Comment: I think this is the way to go, it's clean and one-liner. I can't change anything on the constructor parameters but inside the function it's ok, besides I can choose which parameters I want to merge. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

There are several options here.

Object literal can be used to assign properties. This results in copying and pasting parameters in order to enumerate them explicitly but results in more solid code and function signature that can be statically analyzed:

```
  constructor(foo, bar) {
    Object.assign(this, { foo, bar });
    ...
  }
```

Arguments can be processed according to parameter list. This results in parameter list that is enumerated once, but function signature is loose, it cannot be statically analyzed and is prone to human errors:

```
  constructor(...args) {
    ['foo', 'bar']
    .forEach((paramName, i) => {
      this[paramName] = args[i];
    });
  }
```

It should be noticed that this is efficiently solved in TypeScript with [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties) and is one of the reasons why it can be chosen over vanilla JavaScript:

```
constructor(public foo) {}
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
constructor(foo) {
  this.foo = foo;
}
```

Comment: Downside to the `...args` approach is that the arity of the function is affected and code assist can't detect the parameter names and help when writing calls. Still, creative.

Comment: Yes, I find the first option that you've mentioned generally more preferable, it's WET but less prone to human errors. While the second option is good for cases when function arguments aren't explicitly listed during call too (e.g. in DI container).

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the names of a function's arguments using this technique:

https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-arguments

So you could apply that to your constructor, then use a loop to match up the argument names with their values (by index) and then apply them to an object.

```
function argumentsToObject( func, args ) {
   const argNames = getArgumentNames( func ); //use the code from the above link to do this
   const resultObject = {};
   argsNames.forEach( ( argName, index ) => {
      var argValue = args[index];
      resultObject[ argName ] = argValue;
   });
}
```

Then in your constructor, do

```
const argsObject = argumentsToObject( InitAnimation.prototype.constructor, arguments );
//copy all the arguments onto this
Object.assign( this, argsObject );
```

Comment: Even if the code isn't minified at this point, a design solution like this one will be a show stopper for client side project in future (the question doesn't have `node.js` tag). It's ok to suggest such solutions and keep them in mind, but a dev should be aware of the implications - not everyone knows that it's unsafe to rely on function/class names and signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Given constructor options are wrapped in an object, which I personally prefer not to mess up the arguments order:

```js
const pet = new Feline({breed, age, sex})
```

you can easily assign them inside the class:

```js
class Feline {
    constructor(args) {
        Object.assign(this, args)
    }
    ...
  }
```

Typescript and intellisence will likely hate it, but in an environment without TS it's quick and dirty fix to pass as much stuff as you need inside a class.

[image]